# Could somebody tell me what's this degree in maths called in EU or USA?

Tags: mathematics, degree, translations

In my country, Argentina, the standard Mathematics course is about 6 years long,  and it gives you a degree with title called "Licenciado en Ciencias Matematicas". Could someone tell me how's this degree called in EU and USA?

[You can see here](https://github.com/CubaWiki/Meta-ProgramaMatematica/blob/master/programa.pdf) the required subjects you need to pass to get the degree (a thesis is also required).

I'm mostly interested in the universities of Harvard, Stanford, Oxford, Cambridge, and the MIT.

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close, as the evaluation of this degree by a university in another country will depend on the regulations of that particular university.  For example, a quick Google search reveals that some US institutions consider this the equivalent of a bachelor's degree.  However, others might consider it to be equivalent to a master's degree.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I've editted my question to make it somewhat more answearable.

Comment: There's still no real way to answer this.  Some graduate programs in the US might treat you in the same way that they treat an incoming student who already has an MS degree, while others might treat you in the same way as students who only have a bachelors degree.  There might be similar variation in europe.

Comment: You actually need to ask your university/department this question. They designed these courses. If you ask them to write a letter to state what degree you'll get, what would they say in English? In my opinion, if include all the elective courses, the degree looks like something **between** BS and MS. I don't understand why would it take 6 years to complete it.

Comment: @scaaahu Well, there's a compulsory year that's not in the program I linked where you're taught Calculus, introductory linear algebra and a few other topics (chemistry and physics for example...). There's also the thesis... As I wrote in the question, the degree you'll get is called "Licenciado en ciencias matematicas", I asked how that was called in english and the administratives didn't know, so that's why I came here.

Comment: @scaaahu I think the OP needs to ask people who have worked in Europe and the USA, rather than his or her own university. This is a question about translation between different _educational systems_

Comment: A Licenciado degree from Argentina is mostly equivalent to a North American M.Sc., and sometimes even more advanced.  But I would expect that most institutions, in particular the high end ones, would only recognize it as equivalent to a B.Sc. That said, on institutions with a fast-track system from M.Sc. to Ph.D., this might not be am issue.